# How to make a Shell TabBar to navigate to razor pages with parameters? - Maui Blazor Hybrid

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I have created a razor component Tabbar that looks like AppShell Tabbar but it's not native TabBar, it acts like a Blazor web view . I am looking how to make an AppShell native TabBar to navigate to razor pages with parameters. Any idea if that's even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Take the default Maui Blazor Hybrid project as an example，you can first create the `AppShell` class, and add the Tabbar like the following code:

```
<Shell xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiBlazorApp.AppShell"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MauiBlazorApp">
    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Index">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:NewPage1}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Counter">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:NewPage2}"/>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

Then change the code in App.xaml.cs:

```
MainPage = new AppShell();
```

And create NewPage1, NewPage2:

NewPage1:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiBlazorApp.NewPage1"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MauiBlazorApp.Pages"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiBlazorApp"
             Title="NewPage1">
    <BlazorWebView  HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
        <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type pages:Index}" />
        </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
    </BlazorWebView>
</ContentPage>
```

NewPage2:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiBlazorApp.NewPage1"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MauiBlazorApp.Pages"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiBlazorApp"
             Title="NewPage2">
    <BlazorWebView  HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
        <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type pages:Counter}" />
        </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
    </BlazorWebView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: How to go to Blazor page with parameters via code? NavigationManager.NavigateTo() no longer works.

Comment: Normally, razor pages use `href` to pass values through `url`, but the AppShell structure does not support this. So you can use `App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page);` to jump to pages and pass values by creating xmal pages.

Comment: The only way to is wrap all blazor pages to xaml pages to be able to use PushModalAsync and somehow pass parameters to blazor page?

Comment: You can try to use [Messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger) to pass parameter. Specifically, you can first refer to my updated answer for new Shell structure, it aims to wrap razor page into xaml page. then in the page's xaml.cs code, use `OnDisappearing` and `OnAppearing` to send and receive message, which bring the parameter that needs to be passed.

Comment: This process is relatively cumbersome, so it is recommended that you use the native Blazor structure, which lets you use url to pass parameters very conveniently.